# play framework and wartremover: warnings for *.scala.html files

Tags: playframework, sbt, scala-wartremover

I finally got rid of the Wartremover warnings for routes with this line in the build.sbt:

```
wartremoverExcluded ++= routes.in(Compile).value
```

How can I achieve the same for the *.scala.html files?
To exclude by directory does not seem to work, including

```
wartremoverExcluded += baseDirectory.value / "templates"
```

does not seem to have any effect at all

I'm using play-framework 2.6.11 and sbt-wartremover 2.2.1 and sbt 1.0.3

Comment: What about `wartremoverExcluded += baseDirectory.value / "app"/ "views"`?

Comment: Like I said the exclude directory directive has no effect at all (the example path was admittedly a bit strange, because I didn't want to post our package structure)

Comment: Better if you can post a complete build.sbt that reproduces the problem.

Comment: You probably just need to scope it correctly: `wartremoverExcluded in (Compile, compile)` and same with `wartremoverExcluded in (Test, compile)`

Answer (score 1):

The templates are not directly handled by the compiler, Twirl generates pure scala sources from them first. You have to exclude the folder, where those generated sources are put. But Twirl doesn't use the `sourceManaged` folder (which I tried first), but has its own configuration key for that:

```
import play.twirl.sbt.Import.TwirlKeys    
wartremoverExcluded += (target in TwirlKeys.compileTemplates).value
```